# meaning of wine.classes in r code

Tags: r

Looking at some of the code [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kohonen/versions/2.0.19/topics/predict.kohonen):

```
data(wines)
set.seed(7)

training <- sample(nrow(wines), 120)
Xtraining <- scale(wines[training, ])
Xtest <- scale(wines[-training, ],
               center = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:center"),
               scale = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:scale"))

som.wines <- som(Xtraining, grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))

som.prediction <- predict(som.wines, newdata = Xtest,
          trainX = Xtraining,
          trainY = factor(wine.classes[training]))
table(wine.classes[-training], som.prediction$prediction)
```

Everything makes total sense, but I just do not understand the meaning of:

```
wine.classes
```

and where it comes from? Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: no idea why there is a down-vote. surely that is a valid question?!

Comment: It seems to be an error in the documentation of the package. I tried running the code as is, and it just gives me an error `Error in table(wine.classes[-training], som.prediction$prediction) : 
  object 'wine.classes' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `table(wine.classes[-training], som.prediction$prediction)`, `wine.classes` cannot be found and fails.

In the `predict` call above the reason it does not fail is because these arguments are not used anywhere. If you check the documentation:

```
## S3 method for class 'kohonen'
predict(object,
        newdata = NULL,
        unit.predictions = NULL,
        trainingdata = NULL,
        whatmap = NULL,
        threshold = 0, 
        ...)
```

`trainX = Xtraining, trainY = factor(wine.classes[training])` are not actual arguments so they are both passed on to the ellipsis `...` and then into `map.kohonen` as per the documentation `?predict.kohonen`.

If we check the documentation of `map.kohonen`:

```
## S3 method for class 'kohonen'
map(x, newdata, whatmap = NULL, user.weights = NULL, maxNA.fraction = NULL, ...)
```

We can see that `trainX` and `trainY` are also passed on to the ellipsis. If we read the documentation of the ellipsis it says that **it is currently ignored**.

Therefore, it does not fail with an error because `wine.classes` is not used anywhere within the function.

As a proof, removing them from the call returns the same result:

```
> som.prediction <- predict(som.wines, newdata = Xtest,
+                           trainX = Xtraining,
+                           trainY = factor(wine.classes[training]))
> som.prediction2 <- predict(som.wines, newdata = Xtest)
> identical(som.prediction, som.prediction2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample in the documentation of package ‘kohonen’ version 3.0.2:

```
data(wines)
## som
som.wines <- som(scale(wines), grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
summary(som.wines)

## xyf
xyf.wines <- xyf(scale(wines), vintages, grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
summary(xyf.wines)
```

When you load the wines dataset, it is loaded a variable named *vintages*. This is the same *wine.classes* you may need.

By the way, SOM (Self organizing Maps) do not requires label values because it is a non-supervised algorithm.  xyf requires label values because it is indeed a supervised algorithm.